# BOT_PRECHECKOUT_TIMEOUT

Tags: python, telegram-bot

я пишу бота для оплаты в Telegram. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Заплатить" (тестовый платеж), то через несколько секунд ожидания мне высвечивается ошибка BOT_PRECHECKOUT_TIMEOUT. Что делать? Вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram import executor
import config 
bot = Bot(config.BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message:types.Message):
    await bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id, 'Оплата превью', 'Оплата превью MAMDES', 'invoice', config.PAYMENT_TOKEN, 'RUB', [types.LabeledPrice('Оплата превью', 280*100)])

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def success(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'Success: {message.successful_payment.order_info}')
executor.start_polling(dp)
```